# Python List: Replace Double Quotes with Single Quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, cx-oracle

I am trying to insert data to oracle db and the values for the columns are consumed from a list. the list contains several values and for empty values (marked as "" - Double Quotes) it fails.
So I would like to change all double quotes in a list to single quotes.

`values = ['50.38146', "", "", 'ABC']`

Here "" is marked as empty value. I would like to change all Double Double Quotes with Double Single Quotes to represent empty string. Something like this :

`values = ['50.38146', '', '', 'ABC']`

I tried below but doesn't works :

```
row1 = []
for x in values:
  if x == "":
    row1.append('')
  else:
    row1.append(x)
```

Any ideas

Comment: `""` and `''` are identical in python they are string literals for the empty string.

Comment: That's true .. But for Oracle DB cx_oracle module, they are not identical. You would receive ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier error

Comment: what kind of string do you want on index 1 and 2?

Comment: kind of string ? Sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: `""` and `''` should not have a difference. If your code fails with `""` then it should fail with `''` as well. There is no way to distinguish them in Python. What you need is properly an encoded empty string for Oracle, such as an explicit pair of single quotes `"''"`, or just `None`.

Comment: what is the requirement of cx_oracle for that type of element in the list, for python it is just a string, do you want a byte string or a unicode string. You can't pass on a unicode string it has to be encoded to a byte string

Comment: I understand for python its just a string but its requirement of Oracle DB to have all VARCHAR(string) emclosed in single quotes. see this :

SQL> INSERT INTO MYTABLE (LAT, LON) VALUES ('1', "");
ERROR:
ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier

SQL> INSERT INTO MYTABLE (LAT, LON) VALUES ('1', '');    
1 row created.

There's no issue with python but its just how oracle db works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to replace   if x == ""  with   if x == '""'

```
row1 = []
for x in values:
    if x == '""':
        row1.append('')
    else:
        row1.append(x)
    
print(row1)

values = ['50.38146', '', '', 'ABC']
```

Answer (score 0):

Get first index of "" and replace it with '' it will replace all the occurences of "" with ''

```py
>>> values = ['50.38146', "", "", 'ABC']
>>> index=values.index("") #get first index of ""
>>> values[index]='' #replaces all "" with ''
>>> values
['50.38146', '', '', 'ABC']
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is because in the code, you wrote, if x == "",
you are saying that if x equals blank. That doesn't do anything because you are saying, if x equals blank, instead, you need to use x == '""', this tells the program that you want to find the double quotes, and using the single quotes as the string specifier.

So, your code would be this instead:

row1 = []

for x in values:

```
if x == '""':

    row1.append('')

else:

    row1.append(x)
```